# How do `Hash#hash` and `Hash#initialize_copy` work?

Tags: ruby, hash

I found one instance method `Hash#initialize_copy`. But nothing is documented. Can anyone help me in this regard with some code?

How does `Hash#hash` compute hash code? What is the logic behind it? What are the scenarios where hash codes are used? Does each key of a hash, say `h`, always have different hash code?

***EDIT***

I tried the below :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\rakshiar>irb
irb(main):001:0> h=Hash.new
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> h["a"]=2
=> 2
irb(main):003:0> h["b"]=2
=> 2
irb(main):004:0> "a".hash
=> 100
irb(main):005:0> "b".hash
=> 101
irb(main):006:0> h1=Hash.new
=> {}
irb(main):007:0> h1["a"]=2
=> 2
irb(main):008:0> h1["b"]=2
=> 2
irb(main):009:0> "a".hash
=> 100
irb(main):010:0> "b".hash
=> 101
irb(main):011:0> exit
```

*but you can see that two hash - `h and h1` have the same `key/value` combinations. But how their hash codes are also same? Its also mentioned in the document- I know. But what the reason is? - anyone clarify please?*

Comment: How the `Hash#initialize_copy` works in Ruby platform- can anyone please explain me that?

Comment: The hash code of two equal objects should always be the same. Note that in the code above you check the hash code of `"a"`. Not the hash code of "a" in a given hash map, which in fact has no meaning. A key has hash even when it is not placed in a hash map.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev `Not the hash code of "a" in a given hash map` can you extend this topic by a code,which might be helpful for me to catch the concept!

Comment: each object has a hash, just like each object has a string representation. Calling `.hash` for an object is a bit like calling `.to_s`. The method `.hash` simply returns a value and this value is used by hash maps to place and search for the given key.

Answer (score 2):

`What are the scenarios where hash codes are used?`

Well remember this: "b ={}"? Now b is a hash and every time you insert something in it the hash code is used to place the new element. Same is used to get a value by key for instance and almost all other hash operations.

`Does each key of a hash, say h, always have different hash code?`

No that is almost never possible. However different algorithms can(and are) applied when collision happens so never will it happen that two elements with same hash replace each other.

`How does Hash#hash compute hash code?What is the logic behind it?`

That is a bit broad and general question as hash is computed differently for different types of objects. What **really** matters is that the method `hash` is called for that. So if you override this method, you can set the hash code for an object to whatever you want.

Comment: How hash#hash method can be used to generate and view the `hash-code` of each keys of an `hash`?

Comment: To view the hash code of a key simply take a look at `key.hash`

Comment: Here `key` is a value of a key in the map. Give me an example map and I can try to help you.

Comment: @VBSlover please take a look at my comment under your question

Comment: `+1` to you for your interest to my pain to understand the concept!

Comment: Can I have some up-vote please? but `Hash#initialize_copy` is still not that much clear to me!

Comment: @VBSlover you really should not care about this method. It is private and meant only for internal uses of hash's methods/

Comment: Is it available `a.flatten` in Ruby 1.9.3? I am getting error - `a =  {1=> "one", 2 => [2,"two"], 3 => "three"}
a.flatten`. **Error** `Line 3: undefined method `flatten' for {1=>"one", 2=>[2, "two"], 3=>"three"}:Hash (NoMethodError)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22705/discussion-between-ivaylo-strandjev-and-vbslover)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `initialize_copy` does some internal stuff that is used by `clone` and `dup` ([Jon Leighton has blogged about it](http://www.jonathanleighton.com/articles/2011/initialize_clone-initialize_dup-and-initialize_copy-in-ruby/)). As he points out, you don't really need to worry about what it's doing, but if you are really curious you can dig through the [source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L1216-L1238).

As to your second point, I think you are getting confused between `Hash` the class and `hash` the method.

`Hash` the class is the data structure we all know and love.

`hash` the method is defined on every object, and returns a "hash code" for that object. Different types of object may have different ways of computing a hash code. These codes are used internally by the `Hash` data structure to look up keys (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Hash_tables) for more about these "hash tables").

That's why in your example `"a".hash` is always the same (and, importantly, always different to "b".hash) - it's because `"a".hash` (the method) is not affected by (although it is used in) `h` and `h2` (the `Hash`es).

Comment: First of all `+1` to you.Can we use `initialize_copy` in our code externally like other `Hash#methods`? If so then a small code on behalf of that please. I am trying to clear the basic concept of mine. So your help will always be appreciated!

Comment: Theoretically you *can* use `initialize_copy` (it's private, though, so you'd have to `send` it), but I'm not sure *why* you would. `dup` is almost always what you would use when you need to create a copy (`clone` is another option).